# Short story set in Hollywood during the 40s or 50s where a movie set has real aliens and the blasters work

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am dimly remembering a short story or novella set in a Hollywood 1940s or 1950s movie set where an actor discovers the weapons and 'aliens' are real. I can't remember even approximately when it was published.

An actor hired for this movie as a last-minute replacement finds out that the movie set isn't really a movie set and the actors playing aliens are, in fact, aliens  I think he accidentally fired one of the 'blasters' while fooling around and blew out a wall. He then has tremendous difficulty, of course, convincing anyone that this movie is an actual alien invasion (possibly from another dimension). I seem to remember that the aliens eventually got wise to him and he had to flee for his life.

Also there was something to the effect that several different studios had bought the rights to this story but it was never able to be made.  I am not sure if this was part of the fictional story or if it was part of the comments about the fictional story in an article about it.

Answer (score 1):

Honorable mention for "[Visit to a Weird Planet](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Visit_to_a_Weird_Planet)" and "[Visit to a Weird Planet Revisited](https://fanlore.org/wiki/Visit_to_a_Weird_Planet_Revisited)" in the *Star Trek* literature which address a similar theme.

In the former, the *ST:TOS* trio Kirk, Spock and Bones beam down to the film set of *TOS*, with hi-jinks that ensue. In the latter, Shatner, Nimoy, and Kelley arrive on the bridge of the actual Enterprise and attempt to act their way through technology that they have only encountered as post production special effects. Hi-jinks ensue.

Comment: I feel this is more of a comment of similarity, and clearly not the story the user is remembering (per 'special mention'. It shouldn't be posted as an answer, at least, not by itself without an actual attempt to answer the question

Comment: I remember the second one; at one point they've said/done something, and find themselves waiting for the director to say 'cut'.

Comment: @Gnemlock [Honorable mention answers seem to me to be part of the culture of SFF.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22honorable+mention%22).